# Modal view controller does not cover status bar

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I'm developing an ios app. I have a a main view and in this view 
im trying to present a modal view controller with dimmed background(black with opacity).
The problem is that the status bar is not affected by this color and remains the same.

This is how i present the view controller:

```
let shareViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ShareViewController") as! ShareViewController
            shareViewController.battle = battle
            shareViewController.delegate = self
            let animation = CATransition()
            animation.duration = 1
            animation.type = kCATransitionFade
            self.view.window?.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: kCATransition)
            presentViewController(shareViewController, animated: false) {
               () in 
               // nothing here
            }
```

Here are some screenshots to demonstrate the problem:

This is the problem(status bar color):
[Problem illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLxsb.png)
This is the modal view in storyboard:
[storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxXuQ.png)

Comment: please share code of ShareViewController if any do in

Answer (score 13):

I cannot reproduce your problem, the following code works without problems in my single view app:

```
let viewController = UIViewController()
viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
viewController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5)

let animation = CATransition()
animation.duration = 1
animation.type = kCATransitionFade
self.view.window?.layer.add(animation, forKey: kCATransition)

self.present(viewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

However note that you should be presenting over the root controller of the view. Sometimes you can get strange effects when presenting from your internal controllers:

```
self.view.window?.rootViewController?.present(viewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Also make sure you are using the correct `modalPresentationStyle`.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 3):

Set your view controller as the root view controller of a [UIWindow](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiwindow), then present the window at the [UIWindowLevelAlert](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiwindowlevelalert) level.

Below is a **Swift 3** class used to animate a modal popup over all other UI elements, including the status bar. A scrim view is used to shade background UI and intercept touches to dismiss the view.

```
import UIKit

class ModalViewController: UIViewController {

    private let scrimView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        view.alpha = 0.0
        return view
    }()

    private var myWindow: UIWindow?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        // Setup scrim View
        view.addSubview(scrimView)
        view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrimView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrimView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrimView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrimView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismiss as (Void) -> Void))
        scrimView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

        // Layout custom popups or action sheets
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
            self.scrimView.alpha = 0.5
            // Animate in custom popups or action sheets
        }
    }

    func present() {
        myWindow = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        myWindow?.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert
        myWindow?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        myWindow?.rootViewController = self
        myWindow?.isHidden = false
    }

    func dismiss() {

        UIView.animate(
            withDuration: 0.25,
            animations: {
                self.scrimView.alpha = 0.0
                // Animate out custom popups or action sheets
            },
            completion: { success in
                self.myWindow = nil
            }
        )
    }
}
```

To present the view:

```
let modalView = ModalViewController()
modalView.present()
```

To dismiss the view, tap anywhere on the scrim.

Answer (score 0):

this code works for me, when I am presenting `UIViewController` with alpha != 1. present `UIViewController` like:

```
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let destinationVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddComment") as! AddCommentViewController
destinationVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext //this line is important
destinationVC.delegate = self
destinationVC.restId = self.restaurant.id
self.present(destinationVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

then in `destinationVC` view controller

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_: Bool) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: { () in
            self.view.backgroundColor = .clear
        })
        super.viewWillDisappear(true)
    }

override func viewWillAppear(_: Bool) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: { () in
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
    })
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
}
```

and set its `backgroundColor` to `.clear` in `viewDidLoad` or storyboard. So `UIViewController` covers whole screen including status bar.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution you might be looking for:

```
if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
   window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar + 1
}
```

The main idea behind this code is, `window` of your application has a window level which is lower than status bar window level. And what this code does is, just put your window's window level higher than status bar window level, and your window can now cover the status bar. Don't forget, this code has to be called on main thread, just before presenting your view controller. Good luck!

Comment: This is rather dangerous. By changing the level of the `keyWindow` you can get very strange effects when showing keyboard (which is in a separate window). Also, you would have to revert to the original level when dismissing. I would advice to create a new window, the same size as the status bar and putting it on top of the status bar, and hiding and showing it when the controller appears and disappears.

Comment: Dangerous things are not public, as we know. I'm just posting the solution that produces the effect just like the OP is asking. Of course, your considerations are right, if not used with care this method could produce some unwanted output, but I could argue with your opinion about the keyboard. Anyways, no offense, your solutions looks better than this. I would recommend the OP to use your solution.

Comment: If going this route, it would be better to create a new window (instead of modifying the keyWindow). Additionally, set `windowLevel` to `.alert`.

Answer (score 0):

Custom animation transitions should be performed using [UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontrolleranimatedtransitioning). Here is a tutorial for this purpose: 
https://www.raywenderlich.com/110536/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions

If all you want is a fade animation you can have it by changing the `modalTransitionStyle` property of the viewController you are going to display.

Try by fixing your code this way:

```
guard let shareViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ShareViewController") as! ShareViewController else { 
    //Fallback in case of nil?
    return 
}
shareViewController.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
presentViewController(shareViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Also please note that `presentViewController(shareViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)` is for swift 2. The equivalent swift 3 would be `present(shareViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Answer (score 0):

you can add this code to view controller for **Swift 3**:

```
let statusView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: -20.0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 20.0))
statusView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
statusView.alpha = 0.8
self.addSubview(self.statusView)
```

Answer (score -2):

You could be extremely practical and simply hide the status bar when your modal view controller is up:

```
    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Comment: I assume that this *not* what's the OP looking for, its not about hiding the status bar, its about covering it. Anyway, it might be a workaround...

Comment: I have found there comes a point where seeking the pure and beautiful solution isn't worth it, because Apple's SDK is far from pure and beautiful.

Comment: Actually, it's, just you have to look beyond your limits ))

Comment: If it's important enough, then yes.